# change of SystemID otrs

Tags: mysql, ticket-system, otrs

I changed the `systemid` of otrs instance, but now when a user reply to a ticket with old system id the otrs instance creates a new ticket instead of appending the reply to exisitng ticket.

Is this is always like this or I am missing something?

If this problem can not be solved then what is the better solution? Should I update the database table and change the ticket number column with new system id e.g. if ticketnumber is

Date+SytemId+numbergenerator = 20110615**01**00001 to 20110615**02**00001

Is this is possible to change only systemid using sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by setting `Ticket::NumberGenerator::CheckSystemID` to **No** in SysConfig. It will make the followup detection ignore the SystemID in any ticket numbers to determine replies.